# react-native-maps android can't get mapview to show maps

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I'm working on a project for android using react-native & [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps).

I've gotten the `mapview` to render but it is not displaying a map right now:

[image: emulator screen / map view]

From all the posts online I think my problem is with my Google maps key. I've tried restricting it to android and generating a bunch of different keys but still nothing:

[image: maps api key]

I also noticed I didn't get any traffic in my APIS and Services Console, even though I compiled several times:

[image: apis and services console]

If you can please help this is for a project due on Friday and this is keeping me from finishing it.

AndroidManifest.XML

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pgdi"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:allowBackup="true"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyD7iphH6aGA9Ek6X-q75EJfFLYyeWi****"/>
      <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
      <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
      <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
      <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

App.js

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';


export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style ={styles.container}>
        <MapView
              style={styles.map}
              region={{
                latitude: 22.78825,
                longitude: -100.4324,
                latitudeDelta: 0.015,
                longitudeDelta: 0.0121,
              }}
          >
        </MapView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
  },
});
```

android/build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
    }
}
```

app/build.gradle

```
project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pgdi"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "PGDI",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.51.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.18.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add your API key to the manifest?

Comment: yes, i've looked at every forum i could find about this problem

Comment: Try set the map region to a different coordinates

Comment: still the same sorry

Comment: Try update the question with some code

Comment: Did you try to adding your package name and SHA-1 certificate in the Google API interface ? (on the page you restricted the use of your API key)

Comment: yes i used "-list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android" to get my sha-1 and used com.pgdi (the package where i have my main activity)

Comment: According to your screenshot, I guess you launched your app on a simulator ? Did you try launching on a real device ? Maybe there is a problem with the internet connectivity. Or else, your **flex: 1** style you added to the map

Comment: Hey, ye running on a mobile device fixed it for some reason

Comment: Best of luck for your project !